# How to approach the value of a part of the harmonic series easily

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives, harmonic-functions, riemann-integration

I currently am working on creating a computer program for cryptography, and right now I need to "teach" the computer how to find $\ln(x)$. It does not have to be very accurate, it only needs an approximate value.

Keeping that in mind, I thought I maybe could use the Riemann-sums as a way to approach the value (I know that the Euler-MacLaurin formula would be more accurate, but also harder to compute, so I figured this would be the easiest way).

I simply take the derivative of $\ln{(x)}$ becoming $\dfrac{1}{x}$. Now, if I want to know $\ln(a)$ all I need to calculate is 
$$\ln(a) = \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{a - 1}{dx}}\left(\frac{1}{k \cdot dx + 1} \cdot dx\right) + \ln(1)$$
Well, $\ln(1)$ is easy (it's $0$), and usually I take $dx=\dfrac{1}{100}$, which is not very accurate, but very easy to calculate. What I noticed is that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{a - 1}{dx}}\left(\frac{1}{k \cdot dx + 1} \cdot dx\right)= 
\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{a - 1}{dx}}\left(\frac{1}{k + \frac{1}{dx}}\right)$$
making it a part of the harmonic series. E.g., let's take $dx=100$, then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{a - 1}{dx}}\left(\frac{1}{k + \frac{1}{dx}}\right) = 
\frac{1}{1 + 100} + \frac{1}{2 + 100} + \frac{1}{3 + 100} + ... + \frac{1}{100a}$$
Can anyone think of a way to approach this value? It'd be really great if it could be pulled off with only using integers and avoiding $\ln(x)$, but since it's a math question now, and my curiosity is expanding every second, any answer would be great.

Comment: yeah..uhm no. faster would be $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$ with some table of small $a$ and $b$ possibly with interpolation.

Comment: Erm... sorry, but computers know how to compute $\ln(x)$ without you and me and MSE, it's built into the CPU, nowadays.

Comment: It is an interesting question (how to approximate the logarithm), but you should narrow the domain in which you want the approximation and give a firm indication of *how accurate* the approximation must be.  Generally the harmonic series converges so slowly as to be useless outside a narrow interval around $x=1$.  Continued fractions are more accurate, and a simple approach in the vein suggested by @mathreadler can be found by Googling "CORDIC logarithm".

Comment: You could imagine exploiting that you can read the 2-exponent $x$ directly from the bits in the floating point format, then set $a=2^x , b = m$, $x$ will be integer part of $log_2$ and $m$ (mantissa) will be ensured to lie in $[0,1]$. If you don't have floating point format then you have the SSE v4.2 instruction ffs (find first set) which will help you find $x$ on any unsigned int format, but this is all very non-math.SX stuff which someone should probably answer in computational science or electrical engineering forum instead.

Comment: @ProfessorVector The numbers I'm using are larger than 64 bits, so indeed, I could split them up ($\ln(a * b) = \ln(a) + \ln(b)$), however, I'm looking for an easy way to approach it. Still thanks for the answer

Comment: You can use the $\DeclareMathOperator\arctanh{arctanh}\arctanh$ function to compute the log: $$\ln(x)=2\arctanh(u)=2\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{u^{2k+1}}{2k+1},$$ where $u=\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}$. I guess that this will converge faster than your method.